# Trying to make script in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a script that will randomly run a web page for me. This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

aleatorio=shuf -i 1-100 -n 1
watch -n $aleatorio xdg-open http://paginaweb.com
```

The problem is that I don't know how to add a random number to the `-n` parameter, it's like it doesn't work with a variable.

Comment: A lot of problems here. First, `shuf -i 1-00 -n 1` doesn't ouput anything. Do you mean `shuf -i 1-100 -n 1`?

Comment: Second problem: already pointed out by Jens below.

Comment: Yeak srry, is shuf -i 1-100 -n 1

Comment: Third problem: the `watch` command will open at a random interval a new page in your browser. This is a loop that will lead you to a crash.

Comment: Forth problem: the title of the question doesn't give an accurate idea of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the shell's *process substitution* with `$(command)`:

```
aleatorio=$(shuf -i 0-10 -n 1)
watch -n $aleatorio xdg-open http://paginaweb.com
```

Note that bash also supports the `$RANDOM` variable.

Comment: Don't launch `watch` in this way. If the interval of time is too short, you won't be able to stop the `watch` process from opening new tab in your browser and your session will crash soon or late. You have been warned.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do everything in one line?

```
watch -n $(($RANDOM*100/32767)) xdg-open http://paginaweb.com
```

For your understanding:

`$RANDOM` is a random value, between 0 and 32767. You multiply it first by 100 and then divide it by 32767 in order to get a random number between 0 and 100.

Comment: Don't launch `watch` in this way. If the interval of time is too short, you won't be able to stop the `watch` process from opening new tab in your browser and your session will crash soon or late. You have been warned.

Comment: So basically you are saying that values between 0 and 100 are not good, can you tell me which are better, I'll adapt my answer accordlingly.

Comment: It is not a problem of values of the interval, but of understanding of the command `watch`. If you execute `watch -n 3 <some_command>`, then `<some_command>` will be run every 3 seconds. This means that every 3 seconds, a new browser window will be opened. After 10 minutes, you will have 200 windows open in your browser. This has no utility, in my humble opinion. After a while, your system will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Don't launch `watch` in this way. If the interval of time is too short, you won't be able to stop the `watch` process from opening new tab in your browser and your session will crash soon or late. You have been warned.